# Textbox date (TODAY) "DD/MM/YYYY "changes when entering to cell "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: excel, vba, date

When I put the data I need. I have a textbox with today's date, and when it transfers the data to my table. the date changes.
For example:
Date in the form: 04/06/2021 4th of July,2021
Date in the table: 06/04/2021  6th of April,2021

So, I don't get why it changes not the format but the date.

```
Private Sub userForm_Activate()

TextBox10.Text = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

End Sub



Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OportunidadesemAberto")
Dim le As Long
le = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
le = [Counta(OportunidadesemAberto!B:B)] 
With sh
.Cells(le + 1, "P").Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: You must know that the date taken from a text box **is a string**. It does not matter that you previously applied a format... Excel converts it according to the regional settings. If your regional settings does not show the date in format "dd/mm/yyyy" Excel guesses and in case of months number lower then 12 it may do it wrongly. You must previously convert the string in the date format you need... Does the date in the text box looks exactly as '04/06/2021'? I mean, the date separator is slash ("/")?

Comment: Very well explained. Yes the separator is "/", should i change it? @FaneDuru

Comment: No. Please see the code I posted. I tried firstly demonstrating and secondly showing how to use your text box string coming from Date...

Comment: Did you test the code I posted? If yes, the date should be correct. If you need it in a different format, now it can be properly formatted. If this is the situation, I can add a new line changing the `NumberFormat` property... I adapted the code to also format the (real) copied date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, look to the next test `Sub`:

```
Sub dateFromTextBox()
   Dim strDate As String, arrD
   strDate = "04/06/2021"
   arrD = Split(strDate, "/")
   ActiveCell.value = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(2)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(0)))
End Sub
```

your code line receiving the date should be transformed in:

```
arrD = Split(Me.TextBox10.Value, "/")
With sh.Cells(le + 1, "P")
   .Value = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(2)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(0)))
   .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End with
```

If the date separator is different, please use the existing one...